# Is "Designing Sound" a good beginner's book?

Tags: beginner, books

I'm brand new to sound design and am looking for a good book that covers all the basics.  In my searches, I found ["Designing Sound"](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/designing-sound) by Andy Farnell.  From what I can see in the table of contents, it seems to cover pretty much every topic a beginner might want to know: Tools, Physics, Technique, and Practicals.

**Is Designing Sound a good book for a beginner sound designer?  If not, what's a better book?**

Comment: I don't know that book specifically, but the one that I had to get for my MIDI Production degree was "Sound Design: The Expressive Power of Music, Voice, and Sound Effects in Cinema" By David Sonnenschein. 
I really liked that book for the info and the way it was presented.

Comment: http://aspress.co.uk/ds/pdf/pd_intro.pdf

I found a PDF of Designing Sound and was looking pretty briefly through it. It handles a lot of the technical side, whereas the book I suggested seems to focus more on helping you conceptualize ideas.

Comment: @Thomas that PDF is absolutely astounding.  I've just read through the intro and it's almost exactly an instruction manual for my preferred approach to making new things; by programming them.  Thank you, thank you.

Comment: No problem man! Hopefully that's not against the rules to post haha. But at least you got it before I potentially get smacked down by mods.

Comment: @Thomas I don't think so.  The publisher owns that PDF and it's on their very own website.  It's certainly not copyright infringement.

Comment: Oh cool, thanks! I found it on Google, so I didn't see the parent website.

Comment: That PDF is not the whole book, only an excerpt.

Comment: Yeah @ChristianvanCaine it looks like the original has over 600 pages and 22+ sections. Looks great though!

Answer (score 1):

You won't learn much from books as they don't grow with rapid growth of technologies. I advise you to look over the manual of the synths you're using. Better yet, go on youtube.

However, they don't teach you the way you would learn by doing and experimenting in my opinion.